# Any tips for windows tech support scammer "trolling"?

Tags: windows, scam

I have a good looking virtual machine setup that I intend to give full control to a tech support scammer and waste their time for an hour or two.

I will be speaking to them through my host computer by using FireRTC and a VPN (https://www.firertc.com/).

I would like to know if there's any way they scammer could do anything to me other than simply destroy the virtual machine, and if so could you please help me find a solution.

Comment: Read the last paragraph of my answer here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/108430/phone-call-to-try-and-gain-access/108449#108449

Answer (score 1):

Don't you have an old laptop or something where no personal or important data are stored on? Would be the "most secure" way to do it with using a VM on such a device. I guess if you send all internet traffic to your VM it should be ok . But still not an expert so i would wait for another answer...
Have fun ;)

Answer (score 0):

https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/01/take-your-sweet-time-how-i-scammed-a-tech-support-scammer-for-nearly-two-hours/

This guy here trolled one for a couple of hours. The whole read was rather funny.